# Does anyone know how to make a start number and end number produce a unordered list of square roots?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, square-root

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make this work. I need the `StartNumber` box to have a value of 0 and the `EndNumber` to be 12. When clicking `ClickMe!` it produces an unordered list of each square root 0-12.

```js
function wasClicked() {
  let firstBox = document.getElementById("startNumber");
  console.log("firstBox is " + firstBox);
  let startNumber = firstBox.Value;
  let secondBox = document.getElementById("endNumber");
  let endNumber = secondBox.value || 12;
  let line = "";
  for (let i = startNumber; i = endNUmber; i++) {
    line += "<li>The square root of " + i + " is " + Math.sqrt(i).toFixed(3) + "</li>\n";
  }
  console.log(line);
}

function isANumber(x) {
  return !isNaN(x);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Start Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="startNumber" /><br>
</div>
<div>
  <label>End Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="endNumber" /><br>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="wasClicked()">Click Me!</button>
</div>
<div></div>
<h2>The list</h2>
<ul id="theList"></ul>
```

Comment: <div>
        <label>Start Number:</label>
            <input type="text" id="startNumber"/><br>
    </div>
    <div>
            <label>End Number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="endNumber"/><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="wasClicked()">Click Me!</button>
        </div>
        <div></div>
        <h2>The list</h2>
        <ul id="theList"></ul>

Comment: function wasClicked(){
    let firstBox= document.getElementById("startNumber");
        console.log("firstBox is " + firstBox);
    let startNumber = firstBox.Value;
       
    let secondBox = document.getElementById("endNumber");
    let endNumber = secondBox.value;
  
    let line = ""; 
    for( let i = startNumber; i= endNUmber; i++){
        line+= "<li>The square root of "+i+" is "+Math.sqrt(i).toFixed(3)+"</li>\n";
    }
        console.log(line);
        
}
function isANumber(x){
    return !isNaN(x);
}

Comment: Please write all the code in the question and not as comments, as you can see - it's pretty difficult to read as a comment.

Comment: Pay attention that `endNumber` and `endNUmber` are not the same variable (case-sensitive)!

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a number of problems.

Firstly, casing matters in JavaScript, so it's `firstBox.value` not `firstBox.Value`, and `endNumber` is a completely different name than `endNUmber`. Make sure you know the correct case of any built-in properties or methods and use consistent casing in your variable names.

Secondly your `for`-loop syntax is off. It should be something along the lines of

```
for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) ...
```

Also, the `.value` property of HTML `<input>` elements is a string so you need to convert it to a number if you want to treat is as a number. There are a few ways to do this, but for this example, I'll use [`Number.parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat).

Lastly, you'll want to render the result on the DOM in some way. Again, there are a few ways to do this, but the simplest is [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Putting this all together, you'll have something like this:

```js
function wasClicked() {
  let firstBox = document.getElementById("startNumber");
  let startNumber = Number.parseFloat(firstBox.value);
  let secondBox = document.getElementById("endNumber");
  let endNumber = Number.parseFloat(secondBox.value);
  let line = "";
  for (let i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; i++) {
    line += `<li>The square root of ${i} is ${Math.sqrt(i).toFixed(3)}</li>`;
  }
  document.getElementById("theList").innerHTML = line;
}

function isANumber(x) {
  return !isNaN(x);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Start Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="startNumber" /><br>
</div>
<div>
  <label>End Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="endNumber" /><br>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="wasClicked()">Click Me!</button>
</div>
<div></div>
<h2>The list</h2>
<ul id="theList"></ul>
```